# How to complement right most bits keeping leading zero bits zero using bitwise operations?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

How can I complement a numeric value that has leading zero bits so that the leading zero bits will stay zero and the remaining one and zero bits will be complemented? I would like to do this with bitwise operations only rather than having to inspect the value to determine how many leading zero bits are in the value. What bitwise operations can I use to isolate only the least significant portion of the value containing one bits or bits turned on and to complement only that portion of the value leaving leading zero bits unchanged.

For instance, given a number, say 9.

9 will be represented in unsigned 32-bit binary form as 00...01001.

For simplicity's sake, consider 8-bit form only.
9 = 00001001

Now when I complement this number I will get
11110110.

But this is not what I want.

I want the leading 0's of the original representation to be kept as they are and to complement the remaining part.

i.e. for 9 = 00001001,
the leading 4 zeros should remain zeros and the next part should be complimented.
So I will have 00000110 i.e. 6.

I know a little longer method:

1. Find How many bit the given number is say `b`
2. Find complement of given number say `x`
3. Extract last `b` bits

Or

3. subtract `(0xFF<<b)` from the `x`

Comment: Yes, both of those methods should work.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth They do work, I am in search of a little better method!

Answer (score 7):

If you had the mask of all the bits that you wanted to affect, it would be simply `x ^ mask` (XORing a bit with 1 complements it).

Getting that mask is not hard:

```
mask = x;
mask |= mask >> 1;
mask |= mask >> 2;
mask |= mask >> 4;
mask |= mask >> 8;
mask |= mask >> 16;
```

That's for 32 bits. Use more (or fewer) steps as needed.

This constructions spreads the highest set bit to all lower bits by taking all the places that the bit has already been copied to and ORing that into the bits to the right of that block, like this:

```
01000000
01100000
01111000
01111111
```

Any set bits to the right of the highest set bit are also copied, but they don't interfere with the process since any bits that are affected by them are to the right of the highest set bit and therefore should be set anyway.

Depending on the machine you're on, there may be better ways to get that mask. Here are some options for x64.

Using `shrx` (Haswell+, easily modified to be more portable)

```
mov rdx, -1
bsr rax, rax
cmovz rdx, rax
xor eax, 63
shrx rax, rdx, rax
```

Using `shrx` and `lzcnt` (Haswell+)

```
lzcnt rax, rax
sbb rdx, rdx
not rdx
shrx rax, rdx, rax
```

Using `lzcnt` and `bzhi` (Haswell+)

```
lzcnt rax, rax
mov edx, 64
sub edx, eax
mov rax, -1
bzhi rax, rax, rdx
```

If you could reverse bits, something like this:

```
rbit r0, r0
neg r1, r0
or r0, r1
rbit r0, r0
```

This relies on the property of 2's complement negation that all bits to the left of the rightmost set bit are complemented<sup>[1]</sup>. A bit ORed with its complement is 1, so `-x | x` propagates the rightmost 1 to all the bits to its left. That's the reverse of what we needed, but with a fast bit reversal it's useful.

[1]: sketch of proof: `-x = ~x + 1`, consider the bits up to and including the rightmost 1, after the complement they will be of the form 01*, adding one to that restores the original 10* while the bits above it remain complemented.

Comment: Answer is quite nice but so badly explained that it appears to be some kind of magic. Nor am I sure that I actually understand it however here is my understanding anyway. There are at least two ways to complement a value, one using the complement operator and the other to XOR with a mask of all ones. Using XOR with all ones, ones in the original value will toggle to zero and zeros in the original value will toggle to one. So how to generate a mask with zeros in the leading bits places and ones beginning with the most significant on bit? The series of right shifts fills in rightmost one bits.

Comment: @RichardChambers is it better like this?

Comment: That is a great change! If I could +1 again, I would. I suppose one final question would be how to know the number of bits to shift and how many shifts to do based on the variable size. For instance if it is 16 bit word do I do up to shift 8 or only shift 4? The shift 4 moves a nibble and the shift 8 moves a byte so it would seem that up to shift 8 for a 16 bit word, shift 16 for a 32 bit word, and a shift 32 for a 64 bit word.  Is that right?

Comment: @RichardChambers that's right, up to (but not including) the size (shifting by the entire size is useless for obvious reasons), you can (at most) double the shift count every time, so you end up with ceil(log2(bits)) steps. You can reorder the steps arbitrarily by the way.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you are going to need to inspect bits in the value in order to build a mask to work only with the bits with which you want to work.

Something like the following seems to be the portable best case. This uses `unsigned long` for the function types to allow for promotion and reduction so that it could be used with byte (8 bit or `unsigned char`), word (16 bit or `unsigned short`), or double word (32 bit or `unsigned long`) variables. If you need 64 bit then you could go with `unsigned long long` in the function `ulComplLeastSig()` with the appropriate value changes for `ulMask` and `ulBit`.

This code builds a mask and then uses bitwise operations to eliminate the leading bits which should be zero. Looking at the machine code generated for the function with Visual Studio release build, the code is pretty tight with variables kept in registers in the loop.

```
unsigned long ulComplLeastSig (unsigned long ulValue)
{
    unsigned long ulMask = 0xffffffff;
    unsigned long ulBit  = 0x80000000;

    for (; ulBit; ulBit >>= 1) {
        // beginning with the most significant bit, turn off bits in the mask
        // until we find the first on bit in the value. this creates our
        // mask to remove leading zeros after we complement.
        if (ulBit & ulValue) break; else ulMask ^= ulBit;
    }
    return (ulMask & (~ulValue));
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    unsigned long  ulValue = 9;
    unsigned long  ulNewValue = 0;
    unsigned short usValue = 9;
    unsigned short usNewValue = 0;

    ulNewValue = ulComplLeastSig (ulValue);

    // use the function with an unsigned short. cast the return value
    // to remove compiler warnings. depend on promotion for the function
    // argument.
    usNewValue = (unsigned short)ulComplLeastSig (usValue);

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

Thinking about this a bit more I wondered if it were possible to eliminate the `if` statement in the loop using only bit operations and came up with this possibility.

```
unsigned long ulComplLeastSig_2 (unsigned long ulValue)
{
    unsigned long ulMask = 0xffffffff;
    unsigned long ulBit  = 0x80000000;

    // complement the value so that we are ready to start
    // creating our mask.  the goal is to create a mask
    // that will get rid of the leading ON bits from the
    // complemented value by starting with all the bits
    // of the mask turned on then moving through the
    // complemented value bit by bit turning off bits in the
    // mask until we need to stop.
    ulValue = ~ulValue;
    for (; ulBit; ulBit >>= 1) {
        ulBit &= (ulBit ^ (ulMask ^= (ulBit & ulValue)));
    }
    return (ulMask & ulValue);
}
```

Comment: No offence, but why would this be better than my parallel prefix generation of the mask? This is going to be a pretty long loop with a badly predicted branch

Comment: @harold, not sure that it would be better, computationally speaking. It is easy to understand and easy to do and should be fairly portable to a variety of architectures.  It can be tailored with a change in the types to different type sizes for instance if this is an application with unsigned shorts, then change out the `unsigned long` to `unsigned short`. I am not sure if the question is coming from some kind of embedded application with a cheap micro or computer on a board or what.