# How to Toggle all bits in a number?

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n = 10;
    int ans = n ^ (1 << 2);
    printf("%d", ans);
}
```

this code toggle specific digits, But I need entire bits to toggle
example: `10` -> `0b1010` -> `0b0101` -> `5`

Comment: `~n` should do it

Comment: Your example: `10 -> 1010 -> 0101 -> 5` is not a toggle of **all** bits. An `int` with decimal value 10 has a lot of zeros in front of `1010`. Like `000...0001010`. So toggle **all** bits would give `111...1110101`. Are your real question more like: Toggle all bits **except** leading zeros?

Comment: Or maybe the real question is how to toggle the least-significant 4 bits?  We need more info.

Comment: Please [edit] and show more example of input and expected output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to complement right most bits keeping leading zero bits zero using bitwise operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28382601/how-to-complement-right-most-bits-keeping-leading-zero-bits-zero-using-bitwise-o)

Answer (score 6):

You toggle all bits with tilde (`~`):

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n = 10;
    int ans = ~n; // toggle all bits with "tilde"

    printf("%08x %3d\n"
           "%08x %3d\n", n, n, ans, ans);
}
```

Possible output:

```
0000000a  10
fffffff5 -11
```

---

There was a new requirement after I posted this answer:

> But I need entire bits to toggle example: 10 -> 1010 -> 0101 -> 5

You could create some macros to help you to toggle the exact bits you're interested in. I've created a few below to get you started. They are probably not the most elegant bit twiddling macros around but should be clear enough for you to decipher.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

// the number of bits in the supplied `v`:
#define BITS(v) (sizeof(v) * CHAR_BIT)

// right-shift all but `n` bits from ~0ull (an unsigned long long with all 1:s)
// if `n == 0` we right-shift one less than wanted and remove it afterwards,
// creating a mask with all zeroes
#define MASKnBITS(n) ((~0ull >> (BITS(~0ull) - ((n) + ((n)==0)))) - ((n) == 0))

// create a mask for a range of bits. Example: 4,8 will create the mask
// ...11110000
#define MASKRANGE(bx,by) (MASKnBITS(by)^MASKnBITS(bx))

// toggle the bits in a masked range by using XOR:
#define TOGGLEBITSbxTOby(bx,by,v) (MASKRANGE((bx),(by)) ^ (v))
```

Usage:

```
int main(void) {
    // some examples:
    printf("%llx\n", MASKnBITS(4));    // f
    printf("%llx\n", MASKnBITS(8));    // ff
    printf("%llx\n", MASKRANGE(4,8));  // f0 == 0f ^ ff
    printf("%llx\n", MASKRANGE(8,4));  // f0 == ff ^ 0f

    // your case:
    int n = 10;
    int ans = TOGGLEBITSbxTOby(4,0,n); // toggle the 4 least significant bits
    printf("%d\n", ans);               // 5
}
```

Comment: 10 -> 1010 after toggle 0101 -> 5 answer : 5 i want that.

Comment: @AMEERKHANB that's not flipping all bits. You want to use xor

Comment: @AMEERKHANB `1010` are not the only 4 bits in the `int`. Think of an 8 bit integer: `00001010`. If you flip all bits, you get `11110101`.

Comment: is there any possibe way to toggle that

Comment: @AMEERKHANB Yes, with xor (`^`). `n ^ 0b1111` (or  `n ^ 0xF`). That's not the answer to your question about flipping all bits though.

Comment: Or you can do `~n & 0xF`.

Comment: @AMEERKHANB Did you find any help in the macros I added? Even if they are not optimal I hope they illustrate how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

As Ted and others have mentioned Bitwise Compliment Operator `~` can be used to flip all the bits in a number.

For your problem though, you can use the following:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n = -3;
    int inv = 0;
    int size = sizeof(n)*8;
    int in[size],x;
    
    if(n>=0){
        for(int i=0; i<size;i++){
            x = ((n >> (size - i -1)) & 1);
            if(x)
                inv = 1;
            if(inv) {
                in[i] = !x;
            } else {
                in[i] = x;
            }
        }
    } else {
        for(int i=0; i<size;i++){
            x = ((n >> (size - i -1)) & 1);
            if(!x)
                inv = 1;
            if(inv) {
                in[i] = !x;
            } else {
                in[i] = x;
            }
        }
    }
    
    for(int i=0; i<size;i++){
        printf("%d",in[i]);
    }
}
```

basically looping over all the bits, storing them in an array and inverting them if the `inv` flag is high...which itself gets high when the first 1 or in case of negative numbers 0 is reached, leaving all the leading 0's or 1's intact.